# GNU Make produces target every time instead of when needed

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have this Makefile:

```
PROJECT_DIR = $(abspath ..)

BUILDDIR = $(PROJECT_DIR)/build
OBJDIR   = $(BUILDDIR)/obj
BINDIR   = $(BUILDDIR)/bin
SRCDIR   = $(PROJECT_DIR)/src/app
SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

APPNAME=blink
APP=$(BINDIR)/$(APPNAME)

all: $(APP).elf

dirs:
    @echo "Project dir: " $(PROJECT_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

# Link
$(APP).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    @echo "Linked "$<" successfully!"

# Compile:
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp dirs
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled successfully"
```

When I run: `make` all files are re-compiled every time instead of doing this only when source code change. I suspect that it is because the`build` directory timestamp is updated together with `${APP}.elf` target but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) for `dirs` is maybe what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recipe for `dirs` never makes its target: it never creates a file
called `dirs`. Therefore this rule:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp dirs
```

always has an out-of-date preprequiste, `dirs`, so its recipe is always run.

Making it an [order-only-prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp | dirs
```

will remedy the unwarranted recompilations and relinkages. But `dirs` will remain
a target that is never made by its recipe, so that recipe will still always be run.

To fix that also, do the like of:

```
ODIRS := $(BUILDDIR)/$(OBJDIR) $(BUILDDIR)/$(BINDIR)
...

$(ODIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

$(APP).elf: $(OBJECTS) | $(BINDIR)
...

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
...
```

Further, `all` is a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html): you should say so:

```
.PHONY: all

all: $(APP).elf
...
...
```

And it would be normal to provide a `clean` target:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: $(APP).elf
...
...
clean:
    rm -fr $(BUILDDIR)
```

Comment: I have clean target - just removed for clarity.

Comment: @Lukasz Hi. The target is `all`. The (empty) recipe cannot create a file called `all`, nor do you want it to - it is a phony target. But if you do not tell make it is a phony target then, should something happen to create a file called `all` in the project directory, make will regard the target as up-to-date and mysteriously fail to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp dirs`.

You make your `.o` files depend on the `dirs`. Makefile will interpret `dirs` as a filename, and search the current directory, then finds there is no file called `dirs`, thus the rule:

```
dirs:
    @echo "Project dir: " $(PROJECT_DIR)
    ...
```

will be executed, which means your `$(OBJDIR)/%.o`'s dependency is updated, thus itself also need to be updated. That's why your

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp dirs
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

will be executed again and again.

For fix, remove `dirs` from this dependency. It only needs to be executed at the beginning.